# How to dynamically check type of an actor

Tags: scala, akka

It is a general question about developing with akka actor system.

I know, it sacrifices static type checking for greater flexibility, that is not the problem. Java does the same thing all the way.

But I'd like at least to check compatibility of `ActorRef`s dynamically. I searched for some method like `actorRef.asInstanceOf[ActorType]`. Such method should provide validation for an actorRef passed through messages. And it would allow safe application development. But I've found no method to do any kind of type check. Its even impossible to check if an actorRef correspond to given Props.

How this task typically solved in akka application? Are there any third-party tools for dynamic checks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `ActorRef` is to completely abstract the recipient. Sending a message to it provides absolutely no guarantees about a response or even suitability of the message being sent. The recipient could drop the message, route it, stash it or handle it. Any contract about handling and causing possible response messages to be emitted is entirely an informal agreement.

Now, that sounds like a lot to give up in a statically typed environment, but it provides a programming model that brings its own slew of advantages which by their design require that you are sending and receiving messages with the assumption that the messages will be handled but without any knowledge where or when they will be handled.

Regarding how this task is typically solved in akka applications is by configuration and/discovery. The contract of acceptable Messages is usually placed into a Protocol object, while the valid recipient for those Messages is either injected into the calling Actor at creation or queryable via some DiscoveryProtocol (itself hidden behind an ActorRef)

Let's say you have a `UserRepository` you want to query, you would create protocol like this:

```
case class User(id: Int, ... )

object UserRepositoryProtocol {
  case class GetUser(userId: Int)
}
```

Further, let's assume that the `ActorRef` of `UserRepository` was not injected, but because it is just one of many *services* your actor might use has to be discovered via a general `Discovery` service:

```
object DiscoveryProtocol {
   case class Discover(type: String)
   case class Discovered(type: String, ref: ActorRef)
}
```

Now you can fetch a user like this:

```
(discoveryRef ? Discover("UserRepository")).flatMap {
  case Discovered("UserRepository",repository) =>
    (repository ? GetUser(id)).map {
       case user:User => // do something with the user
    }
}
```

The above condenses discovery and calls into a chain of `ask` operations. Chances are you would want to cache the discovered ref and or hand off the retrieved user to some other Actor that's doing the work, breaking each '?' into a `!` and a matching `receive` in the same or different actor.

This last point illustrates the power of the actor model. In a traditional `request => response` model, the `requestor` and recipient of the `response` would have to be the same just by virtue of function signatures, but in the actor model, you can send from one actor, spawn a worker that will handle the response, etc.

Comment: This power costs too much. But I cannot do anything about it. Welcome back to a C world!

Comment: I've spent the past two months in a love/hate state with Actors. You give up so much in discoverable flow and type safety, but you get some incredibly useful concurrency and state management constructs. I've now settled into using a Future based API for anything that is request/response based and use Actors as plumbing under the hood for those aspects where i need to control concurrent access. Oh, and Akka Cluster is amazingly useful plumbing for distributing your computing.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that an actor is not only encapsulated behind an actor ref, but that the physical location of an actor is also unknown. An actor can be running on another physical server or VM. You can't call instanceOf on an object in another VM - how can you expect to get the class of an actor then?

Now, when building, I would recommend you consider that all actors are remote via Akka's location transparency. (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/remoting.html) If you assume all actors are remote, suddenly you'll think about your designs a little differently. Think of Akka as a Distribution Toolkit - that is its primary benefit!

If you're trying to reflect on actors during runtime, then there is probably something wrong with your design. Instead, you need to know what messages actors can accept and respond to.

If you really want to know what an actor can and can't do, then you could think of modelling some sort of "Accepts" method where an actor would reply with the current version of the described API that the actor implements for example - in this way your client and server can talk back and forth about what capabilities etc are supported dynamically during runtime.

I hope that contributes something to the discussion - just remember to always think of an actor as something that's running somewhere else and you'll design appropriately. The benefit of doing so is that you'll be able to scale out your applications with very minimal effort if your user base unexpectedly explodes!

Comment: I'm using actors local only. Because they are said to be natural scala way for multi threading.

Comment: I would argue that you should consider using futures unless you need state or distribution. Actors can unnecessarily add complexity and remove type safety. The core benefit is the encapsulation of state, so if you're writing pure FP w/o state, futures can be simpler, easier, and more typesafe. See: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/212754/when-is-it-not-good-to-use-actors-in-akka-erlang